# GraphQL string concatenation or interpolation

Tags: string, graphql

I'm using GitHub API v 4 to learn GraphQL. Here is a broken query to fetch blobs (files) and their text content for a given branch:

```
query GetTree($branch: String = "master") {
  repository(name: "blog-content", owner: "lzrski") {
    branch: ref(qualifiedName: "refs/heads/${branch}") {
      name
      target {
        ... on Commit {
          tree {
            entries {
              name
              object {
                ... on Blob {
                  isBinary
                  text
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you see on line 3 there is my attempt of guessing interpolation syntax, but it does not work - I leave it as an illustration of my intention.

I could provide a fully qualified name for a revision, but that doesn't seem particularly elegant. Is there any GraphQL native way of manipulating strings?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't think there's anything in the [GraphQL specification](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/#sec-String-Value) that specifically outlines any methods for manipulating string values within a query.

However, when utilizing GraphQL queries within an actual application, you will provide most of the arguments for your query by utilizing variables that are passed alongside your query inside your request. So rather than being done inside your query, most of your string manipulation will be done within your client code when composing the JSON that will represent your variables.

Comment: can you give an example referring to the one of the OP? I cannot imagine how to use JSON with variables? Should `qualifiedName: "refs/heads/${branch}"` be a json object which is then used in graphql as a variable?

Comment: Referring to my comment one hour ago, I got it with this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54432031/1705829) with a `request` with `query` and `variables` as `data`.