# How to udpate an entry in graphql using variables

Tags: graphql, strapi

I'm using GraphQL plugin with strapi cms if it matters.

I cannot figure out how to update an existing query using a dynamic variable. My original mutation without using variables:

```js
mutation {
  updateExam(input: {
    where: {
      id: "1234"
    },
    data: {
      questions: "hello"
    }
  }) {
    exam {
      questions
    }
  }
}
```

I learned that if I would like to create a new entry using variables I should write it like so (answer by David Maze here: [How to pass JSON object in grpahql and strapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54427105/how-to-pass-json-object-in-grpahql-and-strapi/54432031#54432031)):

```js
const response = await strap.request('POST', '/graphql', {
  data: {
    query: `mutation CreateExam($input: CreateExamInput!) {
  createExam(input: $input) {
    exam { name, desription, time, questions }
  }
}`,
    variables: {
      input: {
        name: examInfo.newExamName,
        desription: examInfo.newExamDescription,
        time: Number(examInfo.newExamTime),
        questions: [{ gf: "hello" }],
        subjects: [this.state.modalSubjeexisting
      }
    }
  }
});
```

But how can I update an exising query? Where should I put the

```js
where: {id: "1234"}
```

How can I provide the existing id of the entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about this strapi cms, but by the way it looks the mutation you have already working, I'd try something like this for the update one:

```js
    const response = await strap.request('POST', '/graphql', {
      data: {
        query: `mutation UpdateExam($input: UpdateExamInput!) {
          updateExam(input: $input) {
            exam { 
              questions 
            }
          }
        }`,
        variables: {
          input: {
            where: {
              id: examInfo.id
            },
            data: {
              questions: [{ gf: "hello" }]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

Give it a try and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you so much it's working! I had to replace the second UpdateExamInput! to updateExamInput!
Now I'll try to figure out why the creation syntax didn't work
Thanks a lot

Comment: I guess you are not setting data: {} inside input: {} object in your creatation query?