# graphQL : Use variable in string

Tags: graphql, strapi

I'm using strapi V4 plugin system and I want to query all comments relative to a specific post.
The default graphql request look like that :

```
query ()  {
 findAllFlat (relation: "api::post.post:77") {
    data {
      ...
    }
  }  
}
```

But I need to add a variable instead of 77, ideally I would like to do something like this :

```
query ($postId:ID!)  {
  findAllFlat (relation: "api::post.post:${postId}") {
    data {
      ...
    }  
  }
}
```

But of course, string template doesn't work with graphQL. Is there another way ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GraphQL string concatenation or interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46022405/graphql-string-concatenation-or-interpolation)

Comment: @kaherdin, did you find an answer to your question?